# php mysqli connect using arrays

Tags: php, mysqli

what is better practice for setting your connection to the database. using normal arrays or associative array? and when i use associative array i have this error Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cms' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\db.php on line 21, but it says that im connected.
We are connected!

```
<?php
//stores the database host,user,pass,name into array

/*$db['db_host'] = "localhost";
$db['db_user'] = "root";
$db['db_pass'] = "";
$db['db_name'] = "cms";*/

/*$db = array("db_host"=>"localhost",
        "db_user"=>"user",
        "db_pass"=>"",
        "db_name"=>"cms");*/

//we loop through each of the array
foreach ($db as $key => $value){

define(strtoupper($key), $value);

}

$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

if(isset($connection)){
    echo "We are connected!";
}else{
    echo "Connection failure!";
}
```

Comment: `DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME` what is this? you should pass variables in mysqli function like this.  `new mysqli($database, $username, $pass, $DBName);`

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thats not true. You can define constants with `define("DB_HOST", "localhost");` and then you can use it like he did in his code. But since he didin't define anything, he should definitly pass in the variable (array values).

Comment: @Twinfriends i have point out error and give only one solution as a suggestion. yes i know there is a lot ways to pass parameters in mysqli function

Comment: @BilalAhmed Yeah I know. Just wanted to mention it that it could work like this, if he would have used define.

Comment: @BilalAhmed i defined it on the start i just commented it out because i want to know w/c is better, and i'm also trying to use associative array just because i'm curious about using it.

Comment: @JoselParayno You haven't defined any constants at all. You've defined an array, but you're not refering to it in your mysqli connect function at all.

Comment: @Twinfriends have you see this `foreach ($db as $key => $value){

define(strtoupper($key), $value);

}` this is where JoselParayno  has defined constant

Comment: @B.Desai Nope, I haven't. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In condition your are using wrong way `isset` is only check whether variable is set or not. `$connection` is set(if its connected or not. If connection has issue it will contain error) so change your condition as:

```
if(!($connection->connect_error)){ //not containing error
    echo "We are connected!";
}else{ //has error
    echo "Connection failure!".$connection->connect_error;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, i already change it but im still getting the error.

Comment: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cms' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\db.php on line 21, but it says that im connected.  im getting this error when i tried using associative array, but the other one works fine.

Comment: Have you uncomment your array? In question it is in comment

Comment: yes i did try to uncomment the $db which uses the associative array. still getting the error.

Comment: Is your password is blank? to connect with db

Comment: yes, i tried using "" on password in some of my projects

Comment: it says `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cms` it means may be you have other password for cms database. try to change db name with one of your other project

Comment: actually when i tried to uncomment the other array (the first one) then try to erase the associative array, there's no error

Comment: Both arrays are associative array why are you telling only second one is associative array

Comment: oh yeah my mistakes i thought the other one was indexed array my bad. dumb mistake

Comment: just different implementation but idk why im getting error when i tried the second one.

Comment: will you `var_dump` your array and show your output

Comment: array(4) { ["db_host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["db_user"]=> string(4) "user" ["db_pass"]=> string(0) "" ["db_name"]=> string(3) "cms" } 
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cms' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\includes\db.php on line 22
Connection failure!Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'cms'

Comment: Got it in previous array you have given username `root` while in second array it is `user` so issue with second one